# Find Sum of Column values based on other column

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a `data.frame` df like this:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~id,  ~name,  ~group,      ~score,      
  01,  "john",  "group_1",      80,
  01,  "john",  "group_3",      85,
  01,  "john",  "group_2",      75,
  02,  "adam",  "group_2",      80,
  02,  "adam",  "group_1",      85
)
```

I want to find the individual sums for the score of each group and store them in a new variable,
for example, the variable `avg_group_1` should have the value 82.5. (because the group_1 scores are 80 and 85)

Comment: [Grouping functions (tapply, by, aggregate) and the *apply family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family/7141669)

Comment: @user2974951how do I aggregate group wise?

Comment: Try: `aggregate(score ~ group, df, mean)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this. I assumed you want to group your data with `group` column values.

```
library(dplyr)

data <- tribble(
  ~id,  ~name,  ~group,      ~score,      
  01,  "john",  "group_1",      80,
  01,  "john",  "group_3",      85,
  01,  "john",  "group_2",      75,
  02,  "adam",  "group_2",      80,
  02,  "adam",  "group_1",      85
)

data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(avg = mean(score, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  group     avg
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 group_1  82.5
2 group_2  77.5
3 group_3  85
```

Answer (score 1):

in addition . to create a new column to data. this is my first answer from my android. it is a little clumsy.

```
data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(avg = mean(score, na.rm = TRUE))
```